# Order of execution of different functions called by different buttons

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have two buttons named  'button1' and 'button2'('button1' is created and then 'button2' is created) . They called respectively the functions 'function1' and 'function2'.When the user press the two buttons , does python run these two functions simultaneously, or successively following the order in which the buttons were pressed?

I want to know that because the 'function1' fills an Excel file and the 'function2' must read this Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is single-threaded, it only does one thing at a time. The functions will be executed in the order that they were called.